# How to interpret the results of a 2 sample KS-test

Tags: probability, statistics, constraint-programming

I have some data which I want to analyze by fitting a function to it. To do that, I have two functions, one being a gaussian, and one the sum of two gaussians. To test the goodness of these fits, I test the with scipy's [ks-2samp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) test. The result of both tests are that the KS-statistic is $0.15$, and the P-value is $0.476635$.

[image: figure]

There is clearly visible that the fit with two gaussians is better (as it should be), but this doesn't reflect in the KS-test.

I am sure I dont output the same value twice, as the included code outputs the following: (`hist_cm` is the cumulative list of the histogram points, plotted in the upper frames)

```
KStest= stats.ks_2samp(hist_cm,hist_fit_cm)
KStest_1gauss = stats.ks_2samp(hist_cm,hist_fit_1gauss_cm)
print KStest
print KStest_1gauss
#output
#(0.15000000000000002, 0.47663525071642981)
#(0.15000000000000002, 0.47663525071642981)
```

I know the tested list are not the same, as you can clearly see they are not the same in the lower frames.

So i've got two question: Why is the P-value and KS-statistic the same? (this might be a programming question). And how to interpret these values?

**edit:**
I calculate radial velocities from a model of N-bodies, and *should* be normally distributed. In the figure I showed I've got 1043 entries, roughly between $-300$ and $300$. I then make a (normalized) histogram of these values, with a bin-width of 10. To this histogram I make my two fits (and eventually plot them, but that would be too much code)

```
bins = np.arange(-300,301,10)
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(v[i], normed=True, bins=bins)
hist_cm=np.cumsum(hist)
bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2
coeff, pcov2 = leastsq(residuals, x0=(0.01,0.,60.,0.01,150.,40.) ,args=(bin_centres, hist))
coeff, pcov2 = leastsq(residuals, x0=(0.01,0.,60.,0.01,150.,40.) ,args=(bin_centres, hist))
hist_fit = gauss2(bin_centres, *coeff)
hist_fit_cm=np.cumsum(hist_fit)
coeff_1gaus, pcov2_1gauss = leastsq(residualsOneGauss, x0=(0.01,0,100), args=(bin_centres, hist))
hist_fit_1gauss = gauss(bin_centres, *coeff_1gaus)
hist_fit_1gauss_cm = np.cumsum(hist_fit_1gauss)

#and the used functions:
def gauss(x, A, mu, sigma):
  return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

def gauss2(x,A, mu, sigma, A2, mu2, sigma2):
  if A2<0:
    return 1000
  return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))+ A2*np.exp(-(x-mu2)**2/(2.*sigma2**2))

def residuals(p, x,y):
  integral = quad( gauss2, -500, 500, args= (p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5]))[0]
  penalization = abs(1-integral)*1000
  return y - gauss2(x, p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5] ) - penalization

def residualsOneGauss(p,x,y):
  integral = quad( gauss, -500, 500, args= (p[0],p[1],p[2]))[0]
  penalization = abs(1-integral)*1000
  return y - gauss(x, p[0],p[1],p[2]) - penalization
```

Comment: Are your distributions fixed, or do you estimate their parameters from the sample data? In the latter case, there shouldn't be a difference at all, since the sum of two normally distributed random variables is again normally distributed. Also, why are you using the two-sample KS test? That's meant to test whether two populations have the same distribution (independent from *what* the specific distribution is), not to check whether *one* polulations has a specific distributions. For the latter case, the one-sample KS test is appropriate, but only if the distribution to compare to is fixed.

Comment: I estimate the variables (for the three different gaussians) using `scipy.leastsq` with a penalty on the integrand. I dont get why I get the same results with both functions.
What is another way to test my fit with the provided data?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you *estimate* the parameters, i.e. determine the gaussian's mean and variance, from the sample data, than what's the difference between your three different gaussians?

Comment: Because I have two functions: `func1` is the sum of two, uncorrelated (the parameters arent, the function of course is), gaussians. And `func2`, that is just ` gaussian. In my picture, in the lower left frame, you see in green and red the two indepent gaussians from `func1`, and in teal the sum of these two, which is `func1`. I hope this made it clearer

Comment: I've said it, and say it again: The sum of two independent gaussian random variables *is again* a gaussian random variable! If $X_1,X_2$ have means $\mu_1,\mu_2$ and variables $\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2$, then $X_1 + X_2$ has mean $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$. The fact that you're see a difference *at all* (even if not in the KS test statistic) is just an artifact of the way you estimate the parameters, I think.

Comment: But that doesnt make sense. If you have two spikes (small variances, relative to the difference in means), and you add them, you will still have two spikes, and not a new gaussian.

Comment: The probability density of $X_1 + X_2$ is *not* (!) the sum of the two probability densities of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Look at the *blue* line in your left graph, which I assume represents the density of the overall distribution - that doesn't have two spikes, does it?

Comment: Ahh, I see. If you have two 'spike'-gaussians around 5 and 0, you will get a $X_1+X_2$ of 5, and never of 0. But the the fit of `func1` is still better fitting the data then `func2`, but I want to say quantitatively how much better. When I google for goodness of fit (or something) I come on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) and the first test they provide is the KS-test, which I am trying to do. How can I get the results I would like to have?

Comment: You *will* get (approximately) $0$, but not particularly often. The gaussian density distribution doesn't have compact support, i.e. *every* value appears with *some* likelyhood - but that likelyhood drops of quickly for values far removed from the mean.

Comment: I'll also repreat this: The fact that you get different results from fitting `func1` and `func2` only shows that your way of determining the distribution's parameters is a bad one.

Comment: BTW, I voted to move this to stats.stachexchange.com, where this question belongs.

Comment: But `func1` and `func2` are different functions. If I try to fit it with a polynomial (lets say 1) I would get a different fit, and therefor a different KS-value/P-value. And with a much lower chance to be a good fit, because its clearly not a straight line. How is this different from my gaussians?

Comment: Please edit to question to show *exactly* what you're doing - we seem to be talking past each other. How do you process the sample values? I'm starting to think you're trying to fit the *densities*, which usually is a very bad idea - how do you even *determine* the sample densities? That usually involes some kind of *binning* to get a histogramm, and the widths of these bins will influence the result...

Comment: Okay, I will. I hope it will be clearer, as I get confused myself right now. I'd accept the move, as we talk more about statistics right now, then mathematics. I posted it here because I am more active here

Comment: You might want to read [Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), [KS-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) and [Lilliefors Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test)

Comment: @fgp, I think the OP is fitting a *mixture* of Gaussians, not a *sum*?